# Generating a php object, two levels deep

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm new to php - objects and arrays, especially. Coming from a JavaScript world, I'm having a modicum of trouble understanding the right way to construct objects, that may easily be iterated.

I'd like to create an object (or array - although I suspect an object would be more suitable) with the following structure:

```
$client_body:
    $cst:
        $title: 'Unique string'
        $copy: function_result()
    $ser:
        $title: 'Unique string'
        $copy: function_result()
    $imp
        $title: 'Unique string'
        $copy: function_result()
    ...
```

I've been trying with variations on the following, but with numerous errors:

```
$client_body = new stdClass();
$client_body->cst->title = 'Client case study';
$client_body->cst->copy = get_field('client_cst');
$client_body->ser->title = 'Our service';
$client_body->ser->copy = get_field('client_ser');
...
```

And it seems that, using this approach, I'd have to use a `new stdClass` invocation with each new top-level addition, which seems a little verbose.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most people use arrays rather than objects for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Barmar - is there any particular reason for this? Wondering if it's performance or preference related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just typecast an array to an object:

```
$client_body = (object)array(
   "cst" => (object)array(
       "title" => "Unique string",
       "copy" => function_result() 
   )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Daan. It still seems quite wordy to me, but I'm beginning to think that's just in relation to what I'm used to from JS. Also, Barmar's comment suggests an array would be better... sorry for my ignorance, but will this actually result in an object, or in an array that php treats as an object? (Not familiar with the language's subtleties).

Comment: `$client_body` will be an actual object after executing this code. As Barmar suggested array it the prefered and most used way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this object class more OOP:

```
<?php 

class ClientBody{
    protected $cst;
    protected $ser;
    protected $imp;

    public function __construct($cst = '', $ser ='', $imp = '')
    {
        $this->cst = $cst;
        $this->ser = $ser;
        $this->imp = $imp;
    }


    public function getCst()
    {
        return $this->cst;
    }

    public function getSer()
    {
        return $this->ser;
    }

    public function getImp()
    {
        return $this->imp;
    }

    public function setCst($value)
    {
       $this->cst = $value;
    }

    public function setSer($value)
    {
       $this->ser = $value;
    }

    public function setImp($value)
    {
       $this->imp = $value;
    }
}

$myObject = new ClientBody('toto', 'titi', 'tata');

echo $myObject->getCst(); // output 'toto'
echo $myObject->getSer(); // output 'titi'
echo $myObject->getImp(); // output 'tata'
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think that's overkill for my purposes this time.

Comment: It depends on what is your purpose, it's true, but you have an example of how to create an object class on your future code which is easily reusable

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use json_decode($client_body, TRUE);